# Azure hybrid connection not connecting sql server database instance using java as backend code

Tags: java, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-hybrid-connections

I am tring create connection for sql server database using azure hybrid connection  and my database server is sql server instance and  it's name is something like this serverName/instance and my java code to connect the database server is similar to this

DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://serverName/instance;database=database;user=userName;password=password;useSSL=false");

and aliasing works perfectly in local but when i deploy the code to azure it's telling can't able to connect to server   "serverName".

Comment: To connect using an instance name you must connect to the SQL Browser on UDP port 1434 to look up the SQL Server instance'sTCP/IP port.  I doubt that will work through hybrid connections.  Try connecting with a port number instead of an instance name.  If you SQL Server uses a dynamic port, you may have to change to a fixed port.

Comment: @shridhar did you find a solution, I am also facing the same issue, locally it works, but not after deployment

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server connection string template:

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://<server>:<port>;databaseName=AdventureWorks;user=<user>;password=<password>";
```

You can change you code like this and replace your port number. For example:

```
DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://serverName/instance:1433;database=database;user=userName;password=password;useSSL=false");
```

Reference: [Connection URL Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connection-url-sample?view=sql-server-2017).

Hope this helps.

Comment: it works fine in java but in azure you can't use /instance for hybrid connection in connecting server so  you can't able to use in azure server.